# React Navigation - wrapping header and tab navigator in Blurview looses props

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation, blur

I am using React Navigation 2 for a simple RN project with Expo. I am trying to get the header and tabs on the bottom to display over a blurred background so I have done a HOC to wrap the library Header with a BlurView to provide that functionality. It renders the blur fine but unfortunately the title, back buttons etc. are lost in the process. Is there a way to do that in React Navigation, the code I use is as follows:

```
const wrappedHeader = props => (
    <BlurView tint="light" intensity={80} style={styles.header}>
        <Header {...props}/>
    </BlurView>
);

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: props => wrappedHeader(props),
        headerTitle: "Home Screen",
    };
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a tricky question that truly got me thinking for awhile.

Here's the solution I've found to get a native iOS feeling **for a tab bar navigator**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { BlurView } from 'expo';
import { BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  blurView: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
  bottomTabBar: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
});

export default function TabBar(props) {
  return (
    <BlurView tint="light" intensity={90} style={styles.blurView}>
      <BottomTabBar {...props} style={styles.bottomTabBar} />
    </BlurView>
  );
}
```

*The problem seemed to be related to the `BlurView` styling.*

Note: this code will only work after setting the `tabBarComponent` option on your navigator as the following:

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  // This part should be different on your side
  Feed: FeedScreen,
  Me: MeScreen,
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
}, {
  tabBarComponent: TabBar,
});
```

**For the header,** I guess it must be the same trick, but you would need to replace  `bottom: 0` with `top: 0`.